# GCC -- compiling issues Imlib2

Tags: c, gcc, header-files

I am compiling working code using all the needed header files, one day it works then next day it does not.

```
functions.h:16:19: error: unknown type name ‘Pixmap’
functions.h:20:16: error: unknown type name ‘Imlib_Image’
```

this keeps coming back I have the header written like this now,

```
#include </usr/include/Imlib2.h>
```

I make a brand new file and put  `#include <Imlib2.h>` then declare each item it say it can not see in the Real program and it sees both the `Imilb`_Image, and the `Pixmap` object. but in my real program even when I told gcc where to look for this `Imlib2.h` in both my main.c and functions.c. One day it compiles no problem then the next day I try it again then it says it `unknown type name ‘Pixmap’` and `unknown type name ‘Imlib_Image’` again. I am getting tired of it. Does nay one understand what is going on?

Comment: Why would you write #include </usr/include/foo.h> rather than simply #include <foo.h>? This is what the -I... parameter is for in gcc. If you have to edit header files like this something is probably not right in your build setup

Comment: might be useful,custom headers are not put in /usr/inclue only system files

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13272683/new-h-file-in-usr-include-linux

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10131624/how-to-include-custom-h-files-in-usr-include

Comment: I had it #include <foo.h> didn't work getting same error so I just thought I'll tell the compiler were it is then try that too, still didn't work

Comment: standard procdure is to have your header file in the same directory then write #include "foo.h" that tells the complier that it is yours and look in the same dir that the main.c is in ..